# Has a pitcher ever struck out nine consecutive batters in MLB?

Tags: baseball, mlb, records

Has any pitcher in a competitive Major League Baseball game ever struck out nine consecutive batters (in other words, the whole side)? Has anyone ever done this from first pitch, striking out the whole side in three innings?

Comment: Ryan Rupe struck out 9 straight for AAA PawSox in 2003.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Five pitchers have done it.  This [ESPN article](http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/wire?id=7812306) from April 14, 2012 lists the following three occurrences:

> 10 -- Tom Seaver, N.Y. Mets vs. San Diego, April 22, 1970
>
> 9 -- Ricky Nolasco, Florida at Atlanta, Sept. 30, 2009
>
> 9 -- Aaron Harang, L.A. Dodgers vs. San Diego, April 13, 2012

Then on September 27, 2012, Doug Fister of the Detroit Tigers struck out 9 straight Kansas City Royals batters. ([link](http://www.examiner.com/article/100-greatest-tigers-93-doug-fister))

Then on October 3, 2015, Max Scherzer of the Washington Nationals struck out 9 straight New York Mets while throwing a no-hitter. ([link](http://scores.espn.go.com/mlb/recap?gameId=351003321))

Aaron Harang's nine straight strikeouts on April 13, 2012 came in the first 3 innings, after he gave up a single to the leadoff batter in the first inning. ([link](http://www.sbnation.com/2012/4/13/2947549/aaron-harang-consecutive-strikeouts-padres-vs-dodgers))

Comment: Great answer! Just a heads up, if you want play-by-play for those dates, you can snag them from BR. For instance here's Fister's game: http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/DET/DET201209270.shtml

Comment: Didn't Kent Bottenfield have some record too?